# What is the correct way to integrate this equation: $m{\frac {\mathrm {d} ^{2}x}{\mathrm {d} t^{2}}} = -kx$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

After some hours without a solution I came here to ask how to **integrate** directly this equation:

$$ m{\frac {\mathrm {d} ^{2}x}{\mathrm {d} t^{2}}} = -kx $$

The conditions are: 
$$ x(0) = 0 $$

and

$$ \frac{\mathrm {d}x}{\mathrm {d}t}\Big|_{t=0} = 0 $$

This is about physics, but I what I can not handle is the mathematical part, so I came to ask here.

Would you help me?

Comment: Do you mean $m{\frac {\mathrm {d} ^{2}x}{\mathrm {d} t^{2}}}=-kx$?

Comment: ooh yes, i am sorry @thedilated

Comment: Multiply both sides by $x'$ and integrate i.e

$$m x' x'' = -k x x' \implies m \int x' x'' dt = -k \int x x' dt \implies m \cdot \frac{1}{2} x'^{2} = -k \cdot \frac{1}{2} x^{2} + C$$

Now separate and integrate again.

Comment: ? could you be more helpful? @Mattos, i said i could not do it

Comment: @Mattos it is not clear

Comment: What isn't clear?

Comment: @Mattos everyone says it can't be integrated directly, and i do not understand the way you integrate

Comment: I didn't integrate it directly. All I did was use the product rule in reverse. Notice that $$(x^{2})' = 2 x x' \implies 1/2 (x^{2})' = x x'$$ and $$(x'^{2})' = 2 x' x'' \implies 1/2 (x'^{2})' = x' x'' $$ So I multiplied your ODE by $x'$ to get the above forms.

Comment: Like I said, he manipulated the equation by multiplying by an integration factor to make an expression that could be integrated and simplified.

Comment: what do you call integration factor? a function? @ManuelGuillen

Comment: @Mattos great, it is better

Comment: An integration factor is a function you multiply the expression by to get a form that is manageable by integration.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor

Comment: @Mattos and how do we get cosines and all that of the formal solution?

Comment: great, thanks @ManuelGuillen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's multiply both sides by $x'$, then

$$x'(t)x''(t) = -\frac{k}{m} x(t)x'(t).$$

This can be realized as

$$ \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt} (x'(t))^2 = -\frac{k}{2m} \frac{d}{dt}(x(t))^2. $$

Integrating, using your initial conditions, and canceling the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ this becomes

$$ (x'(t))^2 = -\frac{k}{m} (x(t))^2. $$

Moving the $(x(t))^2$ to the other side, we get

$$\left(\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}\right)^2 = -\frac{k}{m}.$$

Square rooting,

$$\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)} = \pm i\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}.$$

The left hand side can be recognized as $\frac{d}{dx} \log(x(t))$ so we can rewrite this as

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \log(x(t)) = \pm i \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}.$$

Integrating both sides, then exponentiating we get

$$ x(t) = A\exp\left(\pm i \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\right).$$

There are details left out ensuring that things are well-defined in places which you are more than welcome to work out. This is meant as a guide, not a full foolproof proof.

Comment: i cant remember why this integral $\int{\frac{d}{dt} (x'(t))^2}$ is equal to $(x'(t))^2$ shouldn't it be ${d}((x'(t))^2$ in the integral argument to yield that result?

Comment: No. Think of the fundamental theorem of calculus. The integral negates the derivative.

Comment: I've never done the problem this way before, but to be honest, I think it really could be taught this way and it would be a lot more enlightening.

Comment: @cameronwilliams It's commonly taught this way in first-year physics.

Comment: @MarkViola not to me at least :)

Comment: @MarkViola Partially. They get to the energy equation and stop almost always. I would know. I was in physics for some time.

Comment: ... Or vice versa. They start with the energy equation and derive the force equation.

Comment: thanks, i couldn't get that about fundamental theorem of calculus, but it was helpful @CameronWilliams

Comment: @cameronwilliams It depends on the university, the professor, and the circa.

Answer (score 5):

The differential equation:
$$ ax'' + bx'+ cx = 0 $$
is solved first by solving its characteristic equation:
$$ ar^2 + br + c = 0$$
which (most often in these problems) produced two roots $r_1, r_2$.

The general solution to the differential equation is then:
$$ x(t) = c_1 e^{r_1 t} + c_2 e^{r_2 t} $$
The initial conditions for $x(0)$ and $x'(0)$ can be used to solve for the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ corresponding to the particular solution with the given initial conditions.

Going back to your problem, the characteristic equations has two imaginary roots:
$$ r = \pm \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} \, i$$
By using complex exponentials, we can show that, when we have two imaginary roots to the characteristic equation $\pm i\omega$, the general solution to the differential equation is:
$$ x(t) = c_1 \cos \omega t + c_2 \sin \omega t $$
which in this case reduces to:
$$ x(t) = c_1 \cos \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} t + c_2 \sin \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} t $$
Often in physics, this is usually rewritten using an amplitude and phase on a single sinusoid, rather than two constants for a linear combination of sinusoids. The above form is easier for solving for the particular solution given the initial conditions.

The differential equation you have provided describes the periodic motion of a mass $m$ attached to a spring with spring constant $k$. Solving the differential equation shows that motion is periodic with angular frequency $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$, or actual frequency $f = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$.

However, the initial conditions you have provided means that you start with the mass at rest position ($x(0) = 0$) and with no initial velocity ($x'(0) = 0$). So the particular solution is $x(t) = 0$ because the mass is not moving and will not be moved. (You can verify mathematically by solving for $c_1, c_2$).

Comment: Maybe i was not clear. I want to know how to integrate it, directly, and if it can not be done: why? I wrote "integrate" exactly to avoid this answer. Thanks anyway

Comment: You would have to manipulate the equation by adding/multiplying an integration factor that makes the expression into something that can be integrated and then solved for. You cannot just integrate directly in its current form because it will not simplify in a way that you can solve for $x$. 

But in general, it is better to solve in this way because the formula for the general solution can be derived/proved, rather than struggling to find an integration factor, if there is any.

Comment: i can't see exactly why it cant be integrated directly. Would you show it?

Comment: If you integrate both sides, you are left with $x'$ and the integral of $x$, again, two functions that are still two orders of differentiation/integration separated - so no progress has been made in trying to solve for $x$.

Comment: one of the comments integrate the equation directly, i am a bit lose

Comment: Like I said, you can manipulate the equation by multiplying by an integration factor to make an expression that could be integrated and simplified. Its not always easy to see what an appropriate integration factor is, or if there even exists one.

Comment: Still i can not understand what you said about $x$ and $x'$, i am sorry, i know very little about maths. $x'$ and $x$ can't be integrated because both depends on $t$? is there any clearer way to see it?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Put $\omega^2=\frac {k}{m}$.

observe that

$\sin (\omega t) $ and $\cos (\omega t) $ are  independent solutions.

Comment: I wrote *by integration* to avoid this answer, but thanks anyway..